# Read inbox messages of a particular number and display them in an activity

Tags: android, sms

I am trying to read messages from an inbox and display them in an activity. My activity contains a button and listview. When I click on the button, all messages from the inbox are displayed. But my requirement is that I need to view messages from a particular number. My application is not running when I get messages from that number when I click on the click button only specific messages (associated with a particular number) must be updated.
Here's the relevant code.

myActivity.java:

```
public class SecureMessagesActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme( android.R.style.Theme_Light );
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.findViewById( R.id.UpdateList ).setOnClickListener( this );
    }

    ArrayList<String> smsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void onItemClick( AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id ) {
        try {
            String[] splitted = smsList.get( pos ).split("\n"); 
            String sender = splitted[0];
            String encryptedData = "";

            for ( int i = 1; i < splitted.length; ++i ) {
                encryptedData += splitted[i];
            }
            String data = sender + "\n" + StringCryptor.decrypt( new String(SmsReceiver.PASSWORD), encryptedData );
            Toast.makeText( this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onClick( View v ) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( Uri.parse( "content://sms/inbox" ), null, null, null, null);

        int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.BODY );
        int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex( SmsReceiver.ADDRESS );

        if ( indexBody < 0 || !cursor.moveToFirst() ) return;

        smsList.clear();

        do {
            String str = "Sender: " + cursor.getString( indexAddr ) + "\n" + cursor.getString( indexBody );
            smsList.add( str );
        }
        while( cursor.moveToNext() );

        ListView smsListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.SMSList );
        smsListView.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, smsList) );
        smsListView.setOnItemClickListener( this );
    }
}
```

SmsReceiver.java:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String SMS_EXTRA_NAME = "pdus";
    public static final String SMS_URI = "content://sms";

    public static final String ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String PERSON = "person";
    public static final String DATE = "date";
    public static final String READ = "read";
    public static final String STATUS = "status";
    public static final String TYPE = "type";
    public static final String BODY = "body";
    public static final String SEEN = "seen";

    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT = 2;

    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ = 0;
    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_READ = 1;

    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN = 0;
    public static final int MESSAGE_IS_SEEN = 1;


    public static final byte[] PASSWORD = new byte[]{ 0x20, 0x32, 0x34, 0x47, (byte) 0x84, 0x33, 0x58 };

    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent ) {

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String messages = "";

        if ( extras != null ) {
            Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get( SMS_EXTRA_NAME );
            ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();

            for ( int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; ++i ) {
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);

                String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
                String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

                messages += "SMS from " + address + " :\n";                    
                messages += body + "\n";
                putSmsToDatabase( contentResolver, sms );
            }

            // Display SMS message
            Toast.makeText( context, messages, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }

        // WARNING!!! 
        // If you uncomment next line then received SMS will not be put to incoming.
        // Be careful!
        // this.abortBroadcast(); 
    }

    private void putSmsToDatabase( ContentResolver contentResolver, SmsMessage sms ) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put( ADDRESS, sms.getOriginatingAddress() );
        values.put( DATE, sms.getTimestampMillis() );
        values.put( READ, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_READ );
        values.put( STATUS, sms.getStatus() );
        values.put( TYPE, MESSAGE_TYPE_INBOX );
        values.put( SEEN, MESSAGE_IS_NOT_SEEN );
        try {
            String encryptedPassword = StringCryptor.encrypt( new String(PASSWORD), sms.getMessageBody().toString() ); 
            values.put( BODY, encryptedPassword );
        }
        catch ( Exception e ) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }

        // Push row into the SMS table
        contentResolver.insert( Uri.parse( SMS_URI ), values );
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find any solution to the problem

Comment: ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
  String[] smsNo = new String[] { "15555215554" };
  Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms"), null,
    "address=?", smsNo, null);
  // Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( Uri.parse(
  // "content://sms/inbox" ), null, null, null, null);
  Context context = getApplicationContext();
  int indexBody = cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.BODY);
  int indexAddr = cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.ADDRESS);
  int date = cursor.getColumnIndex(SmsReceiver.DATE);

Comment: try adding this content resolver and give that string array and number

Comment: ok thanks you can answer your own question and mark it as answered ....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870230/read-all-sms-from-a-particular-sender

Or use contact_id

Comment: I believe [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545661/android-get-sms-from-inbox-optimized-way-to-read-all-messages-and-group-them/14783264#14783264) has the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

try this code you get sms for pertucular number:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> sms_id = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> sms_num = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> sms_Name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> sms_dt = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> sms_body = new ArrayList<String>();

    // private ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Uri myMessage = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = cr.query(myMessage, new String[] { "_id", "address", "date",
                "body", "read" }, "address = '+9180009'", null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);
        getSmsLogs(c, MainActivity.this);

    }

    public void getSmsLogs(Cursor c, Context con) {

        if (sms_num.size() > 0) {
            sms_id.clear();
            sms_num.clear();
            sms_Name.clear();
            sms_body.clear();
            sms_dt.clear();
        }
        try {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")) == null) {
                        c.moveToNext();
                        continue;
                    }
                    String Number = c.getString(
                            c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
                    String _id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"))
                            .toString();
                    String dat = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"))
                            .toString();
                    String Body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"))
                            .toString();
                    Log.e("Body-->", "" + Body);
                    sms_id.add(_id);
                    sms_num.add(Number);
                    sms_body.add(Body);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

check log for sms body: you have to use below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 1):

add an if statement in your loop to match the selected number

```
String selectedNumber;
// copy the selected number to selectedNumber
do {
        if(cursor.getString( indexAddr ).equals(selectedNumber))
        {
           String str = "Sender: " + cursor.getString( indexAddr ) + "\n" +     cursor.getString( indexBody );
           smsList.add( str );
        }
    }
while( cursor.moveToNext() );
```

Here only the messages from number matching the selected number will be added to smsList. It is an old question but i hope it will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read messages only from particular number you need to somehow filter your data.

This example filter cursor and sort it.

```
      selection = "_id = " + 15;
      Cursor curSms = context.getContentResolver().query(smsUri, null, selection,   null, "date ASC");
```