# Android SMS How to get content when you have number

Tags: android, sms

I have just one question.
How can I get SMS content(messages) for phone number

input     --> output 
785453884 --> messegaes "some text1"

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870230/read-all-sms-from-a-particular-sender

Comment: So i need use this query<br/>

'code'Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, "address='123456789'", null, "date desc"); <br/>

and change adress for each of my adress (i try make app where is sms history for all number)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [link](http://khurramitdeveloper.blogspot.in/2013/07/receive-sms-using-android.html)

Using following lines you will get the number of the person who sent the SMS.

```
SmsMessage SMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
String sender = SMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
```

Using condition you can check specific senders number.