# Reading a message in inbox from a particular contact

Tags: android, sms, inbox

I want to read sms from my inbox. Here i want to read a specific message. Suppose mark has sent me a message i just want to make a query which will return the cursor indicating only Mark message .i have tried something like this but it is not working for me

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolverSender.query(
            Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null,"address =?"
            ,smsNo, null);
```

Comment: maybe this link help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15004807/401403

Comment: i have already done the things that the link you suggested .