# Filter SMS from a specified numbers and display

Tags: android

Is it possible in android to filter the SMS from a specific number in android.And save it in a specific database.and the SMS should not be visible in the inbox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have yo do this in 3 step:

1. read SMS from Specific number you have to look in to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15638148/1168654) then after
2. you have to create Database for store all info about SMS(like id, body, number, time) for that check this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)
3. you have to Delete SMS from INBOX check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/439486/1168654) for delete SMS.

add below permission for do all step:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 2):

ya is it possible.

in mainfest file add following code:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.Sms_BReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

after that create a  class use following code

```
     public class Sms_BReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
         SmsMessage[] messageString = null;

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        messageString = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for (i = 0; i < messageString.length; i++) {
          messageString[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    }

        Phone_no = messageString[0].getOriginatingAddress();
        Message_body = messageString[0].getMessageBody();
        Time = messageString[0].getTimestampMillis();

        CharSequence text = str;
        Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    if (Phone_no.contains(here check no to filter) {
             here delete message form inbox 
             and save in our own db 

    } else  {

    }


 }
```

i hope this code will use full for u

Comment: I don't where this code came from, it's all over the internet. How can this possibly function? Look at this line: messageString[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]); You cannot convert a byte into a byte[]. Also .createFromPdu() takes a byte[] as arg NOT a byte which is what pdus[i] is.